# WinRT headers fail PREfast due to C6101 in WindowsNumerics.inl

Tags: c++-winrt

Enabling PREfast static analysis checks in an existing project I have yields many instances of the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\WindowsNumerics.inl(2375) : warning C6101: Returning uninitialized memory ‘*scale’. A successful path through the function does not set the named Out parameter. Annotate this function with Success(return) if returning FALSE indicates failure.: Lines: 2375, 2379, 2381, 2383, 2375
```

This may be triggered by including any of the following headers:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.FileProperties.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Media.Capture.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Data.Json.h>
```

but all instances I've seen so far seem common to WindowsNumerics.inl.

This prevents us from enabling PREfast on winrt projects without adding specific suppressions in our code as a workaround. Should we expect winrt headers to pass these checks? Will this be addressed in a future release?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case of the header missing `_Success_(return != false)` annotation on the **invert** and **decompose** functions.

This bug is still present in the latest public Windows SDK (22000).

I'll see if I can find the owner to file a bug for a future Windows SDK release.

> You haven't mentioned which toolset you are using, but you should take a look at [/external](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/external-external-headers-diagnostics) switch.

Comment: FYI this was fixed with this bug item: https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/OS/_workitems/edit/37420735/